# Web.config connectionStrings for Oracle database

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am trying to connect to the oracle database which is located in the Oracle server but i couldn`t figure it out how to get the connectionStrings settings working. I have got a separate server for Oracle and separate server for MS SQL

**This is the working connectionStrings for the SQL database:**

```
<add name="connectionPRO" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER1;Initial Catalog=myDatabaseName;Integrated Security=False;User Id=USER1;Password=PASS1;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
```

**I am trying this for the Oracle but it doesn`t work**

```
<add name="connectionPRO" connectionString="Data Source={SERVER2}; Catalog=myDatabaseName; User ID={USER2};Password={PASS2};pooling=true;min pool size=5;Max Pool Size=60" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
```

Comment: Have you checked this? http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: It would help to post the code you are using to extract this connection string and how you are using it

Answer (score 0):

you can get the connection strings from: [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/)

If you want to omit the tnsnames.ora file, use:

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));
User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```